# CDH cluster installation failing in "distributing" stage- failed due to stall on seeded torrent

Tags: cluster-computing, failed-installation, torrent

[image]

Hi,

We are trying to install CDH cluster on Redhat 7 remote server using cloudera-installer.bin file,  in standalone mode( we have only 1 host) . We are specifying hostname/ip address of the machine during installation , it is able to resolve it. But the installation halts during parcel distribution stage. Here are the logs of cloudera-scm-agent :(We tried both cloudera express edition and entrerprise trial version too)

['http://INHUSZ1-V250152:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel'] location=/opt/cloudera/parcels/.flood/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel progress=0]
[03/Oct/2018 10:11:55 +0000] 28315 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Current state: CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel [totalDownloaded=0 totalSize=2120090032 upload=0 state=downloading seed=['http://INHUSZ1-V250152:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel'] location=/opt/cloudera/parcels/.flood/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel progress=0]
[03/Oct/2018 10:11:57 +0000] 28315 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Current state: CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel [totalDownloaded=0 totalSize=2120090032 upload=0 state=downloading seed=['http://INHUSZ1-V250152:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel'] location=/opt/cloudera/parcels/.flood/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel progress=0]
[03/Oct/2018 10:11:59 +0000] 28315 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Current state: CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel [totalDownloaded=0 totalSize=2120090032 upload=0 state=downloading seed=['http://INHUSZ1-V250152:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel'] location=/opt/cloudera/parcels/.flood/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4-el7.parcel progress=0]

Please let us know what can be done

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error message and stall during install at parcel distribution stage.
Installing a single node (test) cluster on CentOS 7.5 with CDH Express 5.15.

Solution that worked for me was adding the node IP and FQDN to /etc/hosts (previously it only contained entries for 127.0.0.1 localhost):

```
[root@mynode ~]# vi /etc/hosts

192.168.1.1    myhostname.mydomain
```

Then restarted Cloudera SCM Agent:

```
[root@mynode ~]# service cloudera-scm-agent restart
```

Installation then continued successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Stop all services.
2. Deactivate all in-use parcels.
3. Shut down the Cloudera Manager Agent on all hosts.
4. Move the existing parcels to the new location.
5. Configure the host parcel directory.
6. Start the Cloudera Manager Agents.
7. Activate the parcels.
8. Start all services.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the corresponding parcels package from below folder including .torrent file

> /opt/cloudera/parcels/.flood/

2. Download and distribute

This is happening because .torrent file is corrupted